# Merging Pandas dataframes containing a categorical variable fails with "ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions"

Tags: python, pandas, merge, categories, valueerror

I have two Pandas dataframes that I want to merge, something like:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'colA':[3,4,2,4,3,4,5,4,5,6],'colB':[7,6,5,6,5,7,8,7,6,7],'colC':[False,True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,True]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,5,7,8],'colD':[1,9,7,3]})

print("Before\n====")
print('dfA dtypes\n------')
print(dfA.dtypes)
print('\ndfA\n---')
print(dfA)
print('\ndfB\n---')
print(dfB)

dfA = pd.merge(left=dfA,right=dfB,how='left',on='id')
print("\nAfter\n=====")
print(dfA)
```

This produces the following output:

```
Before
====
dfA dtypes
------
colA    int64
colB    int64
colC     bool
id      int64
dtype: object

dfA
---
   colA  colB   colC  id
0     3     7  False   1
1     4     6   True   2
2     2     5   True   3
3     4     6  False   4
4     3     5  False   5
5     4     7   True   6
6     5     8  False   7
7     4     7   True   8
8     5     6   True   9
9     6     7   True  10

dfB
---
   colD  id
0     1   2
1     9   5
2     7   7
3     3   8

After
=====
   colA  colB   colC  id  colD
0     3     7  False   1   NaN
1     4     6   True   2   1.0
2     2     5   True   3   NaN
3     4     6  False   4   NaN
4     3     5  False   5   9.0
5     4     7   True   6   NaN
6     5     8  False   7   7.0
7     4     7   True   8   3.0
8     5     6   True   9   NaN
9     6     7   True  10   NaN
```

... which is exactly what I would expect and want. However, if I convert one of the columns to a categorical variable before merging as follows:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'colA':[3,4,2,4,3,4,5,4,5,6],'colB':[7,6,5,6,5,7,8,7,6,7],'colC':[False,True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,True]})
dfA['colC'] = dfA['colC'].astype('category',categories=[True,False],ordered=True)
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,5,7,8],'colD':[1,9,7,3]})

dfA = pd.merge(left=dfA,right=dfB,how='left',on='id')
```

... the merge fails with the error:

```
/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim, fastpath)
    104             ndim = values.ndim
    105         elif values.ndim != ndim:
--> 106             raise ValueError('Wrong number of dimensions')
    107         self.ndim = ndim
    108 

ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions
```

But when I check the dimensions of each dataframe (using df.ndim()), both have 2 dimensions. Why should such an apparently innocuous change cause pd.merge() to fail – or have I failed to understand how the category type is meant to be used?

I'm using Python 3.4.1 and Pandas 0.20.1

Comment: This seems like a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9426). It works on pandas versions `0.15.1` and older, but I don't think it has been fixed as of yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've submitted it as an issue at Pandas GitHub.

Comment: No problem. Want me to write an answer?

Comment: Pandas have agreed that this is a bug. If you were able to write a patch and send a PR, I'm sure they would be delighted :-)

Comment: Huh... no chance of that happening... I meant an answer to this question ;p

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue in my code. I think it might be **something wrong with converting bool to category.** I've tried merging data frames with other type categorical variables besides bool ones, none of them failed.

My guess is since bool variable can only be either True or False, if there's no match during merging, it would be impossible to extend categories to include missing data value as -1.

**So, a little work around here is converting bool variable to int before converting it to categorical variable. After merging, rename the categories.**

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'colA':[3,4,2,4,3,4,5,4,5,6],'colB':[7,6,5,6,5,7,8,7,6,7],'colC':[False,True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,True]})
dfA['colC'] = dfA['colC'].astype('int')
dfA['colC'] = dfA['colC'].astype('category',categories=[0,1], ordered=True)
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,5,7,8],'colD':[1,9,7,3]})

dfA = pd.merge(left=dfA,right=dfB,how='left',on='id')
dfA['colC'].cat.categories=[False, True]

dfA
Out[0]: 
   colA  colB   colC  id  colD
0     3     7  False   1   NaN
1     4     6   True   2   1.0
2     2     5   True   3   NaN
3     4     6  False   4   NaN
4     3     5  False   5   9.0
5     4     7   True   6   NaN
6     5     8  False   7   7.0
7     4     7   True   8   3.0
8     5     6   True   9   NaN
9     6     7   True  10   NaN
```